# BS4 Not Locating Element in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am somewhat new to Python and can't for the life of me figure out why the following code isn’t pulling the element I am trying to get.

It currently returns:

```
for player in all_players:

    player_first, player_last = player.split()
    player_first = player_first.lower()
    player_last = player_last.lower()
    first_name_letters = player_first[:2]
    last_name_letters = player_last[:5]

    player_url_code = '/{}/{}{}01'.format(last_name_letters[0], last_name_letters, first_name_letters)
    player_url = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/players' + player_url_code + '.html'
    print(player_url) #test
    req = urlopen(player_url)
    soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(req, 'lxml')
    wrapper = soup.find('div', id='all_advanced_pbp')
    table = wrapper.find('div', class_='table_outer_container')


    for td in table.find_all('td'):
        player_pbp_data.append(td.get_text())
```

Currently returning:

```
--> for td in table.find_all('td'):
        player_pbp_data.append(td.get_text()) #if this works, would like to 

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Note: iterating through children of the wrapper object returns:

`< div class="table_outer_container" >` as part of the tree.

Thanks!

Comment: A litlle check `if table is not None:` could be an idea

Comment: Definitely overlooked that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `table` contains the data you expect.

For example https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdulka01.html doesn't seem to contain a `div` with `id='all_advanced_pbp'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly pass the html instead:

```
bs.BeautifulSoup(the_html, 'html.parser')
```

Answer (score 0):

I trie to extract data from the url you gave but it did not get full DOM. after then i try to access the page with browser with javascrip and without javascrip, i know website need javascrip to load some data. But the page like `players` it need not. The simple way to get dynamic data is using selenium

This is my test code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

player_pbp_data = []

def get_list(t="a"):
    with requests.Session() as se:
        url = "https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/{}/".format(t)
        req = se.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text,"lxml")
        with open("a.html","wb") as f:
            f.write(req.text.encode())
        table = soup.find("div",class_="table_wrapper setup_long long")
        players = {player.a.text:"https://www.basketball-reference.com"+player.a["href"] for player in table.find_all("th",class_="left ")}


def get_each_player(player_url="https://www.basketball-reference.com/players/a/abdulta01.html"):

    with webdriver.Chrome() as ph:
        ph.get(player_url)
        text = ph.page_source

    '''
    with requests.Session() as se:
        text = se.get(player_url).text
    '''

    soup = BeautifulSoup(text, 'lxml')
    try:
        wrapper = soup.find('div', id='all_advanced_pbp')
        table = wrapper.find('div', class_='table_outer_container')
        for td in table.find_all('td'):
            player_pbp_data.append(td.get_text())
    except Exception as e:
        print("This page dose not contain pbp")



get_each_player()
```